# ideals in the ring of analytic functions on the circle

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, ring-theory

I know that the maximal ideals of the ring of analytic functions on the circle are the functions vanishing at a point. (for both real valued or complex valued). How does one prove that the ring of complex valued real analytic functions on the unit circle is a PID?

Also, in the ring of real valued real analytic funvtions on the circle, I know that every ideal can be factorized as products of maximal ideals- I = M_1^{a_1}M_2^{a_2}.....M_k^{a_k} with M_i maximal. What I can't prove is that **precisely** those ideals are principal for which the sum a_1+ ....+a_k is even. Also, which element generates this principal ideal?

Comment: it is not a PID, since $(\sin(t/2)^2, \sin(t/2+\pi)^2)$ is not a principal ideal. It is not even a UFD, since $\sin(t/2)^2 \cos(t)$ has two possible factorizations